# Поток FileWriter

Tags: java, io

В общем, не могу разобраться как сделать что-бы в файл записывался результат каждого цикла, а не последнего, подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно решить:

```
 public void task6Met() throws IOException {
    String name = s.nextLine();
    for (int i = 0; i < listok.size(); i+=5){
        if(name.equals(listok.get(i))){
            System.out.println(listok.get(i+1) +" "+listok.get(i+2) +" "+listok.get(i+3) +" "+listok.get(i+4));
            String file = listok.get(i+1) +" "+listok.get(i+2) +" "+listok.get(i+3) +" "+listok.get(i+4);
            Writer.write(file);
        }
    }
}

public class CSVwrite {
    protected void write(String string) throws IOException {
        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("Ex.txt");
        writer.write(string);
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("Ex.txt",true)
```

включает append мод

Comment: Спасибо, долго не понимал почему append не работает.

Comment: @VictorVasyuk если ответ помог вам, отметьте его решением.